# Is there a `eval()` and `do.call()` in one primitive function?

Tags: r

Is there a function in R, which treats evaluates variable and call it if it's class is `function`.

```
a <- 1
b <- function() 2
```

So I expect return from evaluation of `a` and `do.call(b)` automatically understanding that second one is a function and evaluating it.

Of course i can make a check with `is.function()` and call `do.call` and in other cases call `eval`, but I thought it might be already done.

```
> eval(a)
[1] 1
> do.call(a, args = list())
Error in do.call(a, args = list()) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function

> eval(b)
function() 2
> do.call(b, args = list())
[1] 2
```

I do expect

```
a <- 1
b <- function() 2

> someFun(a)
1
> someFun(b)
2
```

Comment: I’m honestly not quite clear what you’re asking. Could you rephrase? What’s the expected output? `foo(a) == 1` and `foo(b) == 2`? If so, what would be an application for this? And why do you want `foo` to be a primitive?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have updated question. In fact it is just for my own curiosity. I have list of functions, which I call sequentially as some kind of `stream`. It would be convenient to process variables and function in the same way. Thus, list of functions and list of values will be indistinguishable.

Comment: @42- thank you, captain

Comment: I got a bit of a surprise with: `do.call('a', args = list())`. It returns: `<a></a>` to my Rstudio console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s hard to prove a negative but I rather doubt that there’s a function which will evaluate non-function variables to their value, and function-variables to the result of making them into a call and executing the call — because these two are *fundamentally* different operations.

That said, as you realised it’s easy enough to do yourself. Even easier in fact: no `do.call` needed:

```
evaluate = function (obj)
    if(is.function(obj)) obj() else obj
```